# MacBook Pro screen broken and was using 2nd monitor fine until I started the process of turning FileVault on

Tags: macbook-pro, display, filevault, hdmi

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 with a broken screen (most of it is black and not visible).

Before I had it set up where I would just turn it on, connect my HDMI cable to TV or Monitor and it would show up on the second monitor and I would enter my username and password and log in.

I made the huge mistake of turning FileVault on and, when I saw it was taking hours I turned the computer off to resume next morning. In the morning I came to connect the HDMI cable to the TV and nothing - it says signal not detected and I cannot see the login screen on the second monitor or type in my password or user name to get into the laptop.

I've tried blind typing and nothing happens either. I also tried a remote keyboard and a USB connected one.

What can I do to get my laptop to display on the second screen so I can log in?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! :)  I hope you come to find this site has a lot to offer! In case you haven't already, it's worth taking the time to read the [tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour). As for your question, can I ask you to clarify whether you only have the one user account on your MBP? Also, when you tried *blind typing* how did you go about it? Finally, what version of macOS are you running?

Answer (score 2):

Things to try in your situation include:

- switch your external display on first, followed by switching on the MacBook Pro (within a second or two) - hopefully it'll get the signal it needs to display the MBP's output
- if the above doesn't work, and assuming you only have the one user account, then switch on your MBP and wait long enough for it to be at the login screen. Then press the <kbd>return</kbd> key once and carefully type your password followed by the <kbd>return</kbd> key.
- if you have two or more user accounts you'll need to use your keyboard to select the one you want to login with. You can do this by pressing the first letter of the username on your keyboard (assuming each account starts with a different letter), followed by pressing the <kbd>return</kbd> key once and carefully typing your password followed by the <kbd>return</kbd> key.

If none of the above work, please let me know and we'll see what else we can try.